# React Native camera works first time then not working (black screen) in android device

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I was using an older version of react-native-camera and it worked fine on iOS. But it did not work on Android. I am creating a function like scanning code combines with taking pictures after isBarcodeRead logic done. Then I tried upgrading this lib up to and met the same problem as yours.

Comment: Please show the code and what version you are using

Comment: are you using RNCamera or RCTCamera after upgrading? there are differences in its method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue with react-navigation router.
Camera stops working after I changing page
This code solved it for me

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation' 
    render() {
        const { isFocused } = this.props
        return (
           <View>
             { isFocused && <RNCamera  ... />  }
           </View
         )
    }
    export default withNavigationFocus(Camera) `
```

Comment: How can i do the same with react-native-router-flux @VipinVv

Answer (score 5):

If you are on react-navigation 5.x then do:

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const CameraView = (props) => {

const isFocused = useIsFocused();
return (
   <View>
     { isFocused && <RNCamera  />  }
   </View>
 )
}
```